# Laravel 4 : white screen after 2 years

Tags: php, laravel

I didn't touched my personal [website](http://www.matteogabriele.it) since 2 years and suddenly I have only a white screen with a ***Internal Server Error*** message in the console. 
That's it!

The website is build on top of Laravel 4.

I've wrote to my hosting service but apparently: hosting side is completely normal.

Any idea is appreciated, thanks!

**Last error log**

```
require(paths.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public/index.php on line 24
```

**UPDATE**

Ok I google it a lot and then I found out that there is a Laravel function called yield() that collides with a reserved name in PHP 5.5 that was not in PHP 5.4.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that PHP was updated?

Comment: yes I ask about that too, they told me from 5.4 to 5.5 but Laravel 4 should be ok as well with that, isn't it?

Comment: Did you check error log?

Comment: Actually I've no errors during these days, only this one
"require(paths.php) [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /public/index.php on line 24" but it's from long time ago so.. if it is, why now?

Comment: That is the first file what laravel try to require from your root directory. It could permission problems, or the file is damaged/missing?

Comment: I've just updated the question after some research

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, got it!

The problem so is the conflict between the **yield** in **php5.4** and **php5.5** so in this link you know where you need to change **yield** to **_yield** to fix that without rebuild your entire site with another version of Laravel.

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/3298407238fd3e212cdf8d829adc6f519b941052